# xslt nested transformation : unable to transnform

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am learning XSLT and trying to transform below xml. But couldn't achieve the task

```
<sample id="7">
<land1 id="8">
<owner>TOMMY</owner>
<type>INDIVIDUAL</type>
<hint>TOM_INDIVIDUAL</hint>
<date>12.02.2014</date>
<text>land details</text>
<number>1</number>
<cost>WIDERRUFLICH</cost>
</land1>
</sample>
```

and trying to convert above into

```
<table name="sample">
<tablename="land1">
<rel name="owner" value="TOMMY"/>
<rel name="type" value="INDIVIDUAL"/>
<rel name="<hint" value="TOM_INDIVIDUAL"/>
<rel name="date" value="12.02.2014"/>
<rel name="details" value="land details"/>
<rel name="number" value="1"/>
<rel name="cost" value="25%"/>
</table>
</table>
```

I tried below to generate the same, but it's not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>



    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:if test="current().count(*)>0">
                 <xsl:element name="table">
                     <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
                     </xsl:attribute>
                     <xsl:apply-templates select="/"
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="current().count(*)=0">
                <xsl:element name="rel">
                     <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
                     </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can someone please let me know where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone please let me know where I am doing wrong?

Well, for one thing, `current().count(*)>0` is not a valid expression.

And you have  `<xsl:apply-templates select="/"` without closing the tag. Which may be a good thing - because if it worked, it would have created an infinite loop.

I also don't understand the overall logic of your approach. Couldn't you do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <table name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <rel name="{name()}" value="{.}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

> every element with an attribute should also be a table. For example,
>   in the above xml, `<land1 id="8">` has children and your logic works
>   fine. But my inout can also contain `<land1 id="8"/>`. Now even though
>   it doesn't have any child elements, still element name has to be
>   considered as Table

Then use:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@*]">
```

instead of:

```
<xsl:template match="*[*]">
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I was trying to achieve that every element with an attribute should also be a table. For example, in the above xml, <land1 id="8">  has children and your logic works fine. But my input can also contain <land1 id="8"/>. Now even though it doesn't have any child elements, still element name has to be considered as Table, but not attr.

Comment: @ajit See the addition to my answer.